# How to make a circle move diagonally from corner to corner in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've created a program to animate shapes, and I've only moved either the x axis or y axis, never both at the same time. So moving diagonally is completely new to me. Below is my code:

```
"""
    Author: Victor Xu

    Date: January 20th, 2021

    Description: Animating Shapes with pygame
"""

"""
    1. Modify the animation of the red_box so that when it hits 
       the left or right side of the window it changes direction. (COMPLETED)

    2. Add a green_rect (40x20) Surface that moves in up and down.
       It should change its y direction when it hits to top or bottom 
       of the window. (COMPLETED)

    3. Add a blue_circle (24x24) Surface that moves in a diagonal path.
       If it hits the top or bottom of the window reverse its 
       y direction, and if it hits the left or right of the window
       reverse its x direction.
"""

import pygame


def main():
    '''This function defines the 'mainline logic' for our game.'''
    # I - INITIALIZE
    pygame.init()

    # DISPLAY
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Crazy Shapes Animation")

    # ENTITIES
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((255, 255, 255))  # white background

    # Make a red 25 x 25 box
    red_box = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
    red_box = red_box.convert()
    red_box.fill((255, 0, 0))

    # Make a green 40 x 20 rectangle
    green_rect = pygame.Surface((40, 20))
    green_rect = green_rect.convert()
    green_rect.fill((0, 255, 0))

    # Make a blue 24 x 24 circle
    blue_circ = pygame.Surface((24, 24))
    blue_circ = blue_circ.convert()
    blue_circ.fill((0, 0, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(blue_circ, (0, 0, 255), (25, 25), 24)

    # A - ACTION (broken into ALTER steps)

    # ASSIGN
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True

    red_box_x = 0  # Assign starting (x,y)
    red_box_y = 200  # for our red box
    move_red_x = 5

    green_rect_x = 300  # Assign starting (x,y)
    green_rect_y = 200  # for our green rectangle
    move_rect_y = 5

    blue_circ_x = 640  # Assign starting (x,y)
    blue_circ_y = 0  # for our blue circle
    move_circ_x = 5
    move_circ_y = 5

    # LOOP
    while keepGoing:

        # TIMER
        clock.tick(30)

        # EVENT HANDLING
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keepGoing = False

        # change x coordinate of red box
        red_box_x += move_red_x
        # check boundaries, to bounce off wall
        if red_box_x >= screen.get_width():
            red_box_x = screen.get_width()
            move_red_x *= -1
        if red_box_x <= 0:
            red_box_x = 0
            move_red_x *= -1

        # change y coordinate of green rectangle
        green_rect_y += move_rect_y
        # check boundaries, to bounce off wall
        if green_rect_y >= screen.get_height():
            green_rect_y = screen.get_height()
            move_rect_y *= -1
        if green_rect_y <= 0:
            green_rect_y = 0
            move_rect_y *= -1

        # REFRESH (update window)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(green_rect, (green_rect_x, green_rect_y))  # blit rectangle at new (x,y) location
        screen.blit(red_box, (red_box_x, red_box_y))  # blit box at new (x,y) location
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Close the game window
    pygame.quit()


# Call the main function
main()
```

It would be great if you could complete it using my style, that way I would be able to understand it better. Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you find difficult about changing both the x and y position of a shape at the same time? - just duplicate the logic for one axis, and apply it to the other axis of the same shape.  If you apply the same step to each axis, you'll move the shape diagonally.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that... I did that and it worked. Thank you so much! How do I get out of my "beginner" mindset? I just started Python recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will offer a more general approach. Define a list of positions (`circle_pos_list`) that the object should visit on its way. Set the start position (`circle_pos`), the speed (`circle_speed`) and the index of the next target position in the list (`next_pos_index`).

```py
circle_pos_list = [(100, 100), (200, 150), (100, 150)]
circle_pos = circle_pos_list[0]
circle_speed = 5
next_pos_index = 1
```

Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) to calculate the current distance vector of the circle to the next target position in the list:

```py
circle_dir = pygame.math.Vector2(circle_pos_list[next_pos_index]) - circle_pos
```

If the distance to the target is less than the speed of the circle, step on the target and change the target location index to the next target:

```py
if circle_dir.length() < circle_speed:
    circle_pos = circle_pos_list[next_pos_index]
    next_pos_index = (next_pos_index + 1) % len(circle_pos_list)
```

Otherwise, take a step along the vector to the next destination:

```py
circle_dir.scale_to_length(circle_speed)
new_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(circle_pos) + circle_dir
circle_pos = (new_pos.x, new_pos.y)
```

Changes in your code:

[image]

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    blue_circ = pygame.Surface((24, 24))
    blue_circ.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(blue_circ, (0, 0, 255), (12, 12), 12)

    # [...]

    circle_pos_list = [(100, 100), (200, 150), (100, 150)]
    circle_pos = circle_pos_list[0]
    circle_speed = 5
    next_pos_index = 1

    # LOOP
    while keepGoing:
        # [...]

        circle_dir = pygame.math.Vector2(circle_pos_list[next_pos_index]) - circle_pos
        if circle_dir.length() < circle_speed:
            circle_pos = circle_pos_list[next_pos_index]
            next_pos_index = (next_pos_index + 1) % len(circle_pos_list)
        else:
            circle_dir.scale_to_length(circle_speed)
            new_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(circle_pos) + circle_dir
            circle_pos = (new_pos.x, new_pos.y)

        # [...]

        screen.blit(blue_circ, (round(circle_pos[0]), round(circle_pos[1])))

        # [...]
```